# How do I deal with split samples for conjoint in SPSS?

Tags: spss, conjoint-analysis

We ran a survey of a sample of over 4,000 where we asked about 16 cards (product combinations). To combat survey fatigue, we randomly assigned each respondent 4 of the cards, so that every respondent rated 4 (not 16) packages. Now we have the data back, and we do have over 1,000 ratings per card, but I don't know how to have SPSS analyze these four split samples. Can anyone help? We can't afford Sawtooth, so I'm also open to any other free software that can do this. Thank you.

Comment: We use R package ChoiceModelR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChoiceModelR/index.html) for such tasks. But it requires strong R knowledge.

Comment: And R can handle these split samples? Do you have some syntax you can share?

Comment: SPSS conjoint command is just basic classic conjoint. It amounts, statistically, to multifactor ANOVA, - see Comand syntax reference and Algorithms documents. If you find it difficult to perform conjoint because the format of that SPSS command doesn't allow it (like possibly in your case where subsamples rated different cards) you can always use SPSS GLM procedure to get the proper results. Once again: classic conjoint is not a special kind of analysis, it's just ANOVAs.

Comment: @Ginagina123 Yes, I used it for split samples. I have only small example near me, it is without split samples. Sorry it is not very readable - https://gist.github.com/gdemin/1936db99f16993000512

Comment: Thanks, if you happen to have an example with split samples, I'd appreciate that!

Comment: For split samples you will have just subset of tasks per each respondent in script above. I suppose there is no need to modify these script.